# Ros2 build failed on mimick_vendor

Tags: ros2, build

I am having trouble building and installing ROS2 on my windows 10 pc. I am using the guide from
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Windows-Development-Setup.html
and I am at the step where I build ROS using the

```
colcon build --merge-install
```

command from a visual studio command prompt ran as administrator. Everything seems to be going well for a bit, but eventually, mimick_vendor build fails. I am using visual studio 2019 (and I also tried this for visual studio 2022). I will post the log file under C:\humble\log\build_2024-02-01_11_30_59\mimick_vendor.

```
        -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30153.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30153.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ament_cmake: 1.3.7 (C:/humble/install/share/ament_cmake/cmake)
-- Found Python3: C:/Python38/python.exe (found version "3.8.3") found components: Interpreter 
-- Found ament_lint_auto: 0.12.10 (C:/humble/install/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake)
-- Added test 'copyright' to check source files copyright and LICENSE
-- Added test 'lint_cmake' to check CMake code style
-- Added test 'xmllint' to check XML markup files
-- Configuring done (68.0s)
-- Generating done (1.4s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/humble/build/mimick_vendor
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  1>Checking Build System
  Creating directories for 'mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7'
  Building Custom Rule C:/humble/src/ros2/mimick_vendor/CMakeLists.txt
  Performing download step (git clone) for 'mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7'
  Cloning into 'mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7'...
  HEAD is now at de11f83 Support raspberry pi zero (#21)
  No update step for 'mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7'
  No patch step for 'mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7'
  Performing configure step for 'mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7'
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30153.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30153.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
  CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
    The C compiler
  
      "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
  
    is not able to compile a simple test program.
  
    It fails with the following output:
  
      Change Dir: 'C:/humble/build/mimick_vendor/mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix/src/mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-wkf3rj'
      
      Run Build Command(s): "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe" cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:n
      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
      Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
      
      Build started 2/1/2024 12:18:51 PM.
      Project "C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
      PrepareForBuild:
        Creating directory "cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\".
        Creating directory "C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\Debug\".
        Creating directory "cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_e66c9.tlog\".
      InitializeBuildStatus:
        Creating "cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_e66c9.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
      ClCompile:
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\testCCompiler.c"
        Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30153 for x64
        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
        testCCompiler.c
        cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D _MBCS /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\testCCompiler.c"
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_e66c9.tlog'. [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles..ctor(ITaskItem[] tlogFiles) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
      Done Building Project "C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
      
      Build FAILED.
      
      "C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
      (ClCompile target) -> 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.dir\Debug\cmTC_e66c9.tlog'. [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit() [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TrackedDependencies.ExpandWildcards(ITaskItem[] expand) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles.InternalConstruct(ITask ownerTask, ITaskItem[] tlogFiles, Boolean constructOutputsFromTLogs) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.CanonicalTrackedOutputFiles..ctor(ITaskItem[] tlogFiles) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL.PostExecuteTool(Int32 exitCode) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.TrackedVCToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands) [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(687,5): error MSB6003: at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute() [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-prefix\src\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wkf3rj\cmTC_e66c9.vcxproj] [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
      
          0 Warning(s)
          1 Error(s)
      
      Time Elapsed 00:00:03.78
      
      
  
    
  
    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)
  
  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\a94a30304988bc0e4e99cbce4ec56fa0\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-mkdir.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\a94a30304988bc0e4e99cbce4ec56fa0\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-download.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\a94a30304988bc0e4e99cbce4ec56fa0\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-update.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\a94a30304988bc0e4e99cbce4ec56fa0\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-patch.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\a94a30304988bc0e4e99cbce4ec56fa0\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-configure.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\a94a30304988bc0e4e99cbce4ec56fa0\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-build.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\a94a30304988bc0e4e99cbce4ec56fa0\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-install.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\b38ba682d5d4334b5a20033ddf7ff70d\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7-complete.rule;C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\CMakeFiles\5e3b6f3a33b3892616a4f59a29e4bbeb\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.rule;C:\humble\src\ros2\mimick_vendor\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [C:\humble\build\mimick_vendor\mimick-de11f8377eb95f932a03707b583bf3d4ce5bd3e7.vcxproj]
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This is the stdout text file by the way.